# I want to loop through List of object in C# using for loop

Tags: c#

I have a list of object

```
my_list = [{ name: 'alex',last_name: 'leda'},{ name: 'john',last_name: 'parsons'}]
```

I want to loop through **my_list** using for loop.

I want to get all the last_name from my_list

Comment: Search for “C# LINQ tutorial”, which will cover the use of `Select`. Also, that is not valid C#..

Comment: That isn't C# code. Can you provide real C# code for your list?